# How to move the next line starting with ";" move to previous line end in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text as the below one in `notepad++`.
I want move all the lines starting with `";"` to previous line, after its end.

Input:

```
kskdjhs;sdkjfhkkdsf;eueue
";"";"dkdkjfhgf;skdfgjhkdsfg
kdsjfhkjsdfl;sjdjkd;sjjdshfkas;sdkjlhsfd
sdjhksdf;sdjkksd;skjf;jshdsdf
";"";"sjdhslkjdf;jjhhkjasdf;
kjsdhfkjsdf;kshjdhfksdh;sdkjkhkdsfnk
";"";"ksdlkjjflasd;lkjlsjdfhlsdf
```

Desired Output

```
kskdjhs;sdkjfhkkdsf;eueue";"";"dkdkjfhgf;skdfgjhkdsfg
kdsjfhkjsdfl;sjdjkd;sjjdshfkas;sdkjlhsfd
sdjhksdf;sdjkksd;skjf;jshdsdf";"";"sjdhslkjdf;jjhhkjasdf;
kjsdhfkjsdf;kshjdhfksdh;sdkjkhkdsfnk";"";"ksdlkjjflasd;lkjlsjdfhlsdf
```

Answer (score 3):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?=";")`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?=";")     # positive lookahead, make sure we have ";" after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]